# Spatial Results Tab window not available in Microsoft Visual studio

Tags: sql-server

I cannot see the 'spatial results' tab window when i run the query below.When i run a normal query i can see 2 tabs showing 'results' and 'message' but not the 'spatial results' tab. I am using Microsoft visual studio2017(ssdt).The codes below works fine but it displays the columns as text and coordinates but not in a grid format.Can someone tell me how to get the spatial results tab.Is there something that i need to download.Please advise.

```
Create table [Spatialinfo]
(id INT,spatialdata geometry,shape Varchar(10));

INSERT INTO [spatialinfo]
(spatialdata)
VALUES ('Point(7 12)');

Select * From Spatialinfo;
```

The result that i get is something approximately as follows in the message window.

```
id       spatialdata                          shape
1        0x000010c0000022400000002840         null
```

Answer (score 0):

*"The codes below works fine but it displays the columns as text and coordinates but not in a grid format"*

The documentation explicitly states that if you are returning your results as text, you will not get the Spatial Results Pane. [Spatial Results Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/spatial-results-window?view=sql-server-2017):

> Note
>
> The Spatial results window is only available if your results are
>   returned to a grid in the Results window. If you specify that your
>   results are returned as text, this window is not available.

You need to return your results in the Grid View to see the Spatial Results Window.